# Fantasy story entertainer hired as decoy/replacement

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to place this story for a while now so hoping someone can help.

Setting: 
Fantasy, various main characters have elemental themed magical abilities (one has fire magic, another water etc)

Main plot points: 
A sleight of hand magician/entertainer is hired to pretend to be a prince(?) who has fire magic. I can't remember if this is a decoy situation or if the original is missing. I remember there was a lot of conflict between the characters factions including assassinations attempts (see below).

Memorable scenes: 
I distinctly recall one scene where the main character was in his rooms and one of the other characters tried to kill him by summoning a globe of water around his head to drown him. He was able to escape by using a tube/straw to breathe.

There was a ritual that needed to be performed by putting the persons blood onto a stone, the people who had hired the main character were worried about this but he dismissed their concerns by explaining he would have a vial of blood up his sleeve and pull the cork with some string.

I think there was a character in the book who was a bodyguard and the highest ranked duellist in the kingdom, but fought with a great axe (though I may be confusing an entirely different story here)

Other details:
This was an English language book (not translated that I recall), that I'm fairly sure I read at least 15 years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[Blood And Honour](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/g/simon-r-green/blood-and-honour.htm)" by Simon R.Green. It's in the Forest Kingdom series. The prince he is impersonating is ill (being poisoned, but they don't realise this for a while). The other princes, his brothers, have Earth and Water magic.

Comment: That certainly looks like it, thanks!